# The space of functions of gaussian random variables.

Tags: probability

Suppose $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Is there anything that can be said about the space of random variables $$\{ X : X = f(Z) \text{ for some continuous } f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}$$

For example, is this space dense in the space of random variables under topology induced by convergence in distribution?

Comment: I had first proved this in special case ; I have now edited the answer and given an affirmative answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume first that $G$ is a continuous strictly increasing distribution function and $H=G^{-1}$. Then $G(t) \geq x$ iff $H(x) \leq t$. Let $f=H\circ F$ where $F$ is the distribution function of $Z$. Then $f$ is continuous. We have $$P\{f(Z) \leq t\}=P\{H(F(Z)\leq t\}=P\{G(t) \geq F(Z)\}$$ $$=P\{F^{-1}(G(t)) \geq Z\}=F(F^{-1}(G(T)))=G(t).$$ Hence every continuous strictly increasing distribution is in your class.

Now let $G$ be any distribution function. Let $Y$ be a random variable with distribution $G$ independent of $Z$. Then $\frac Z n +Y \to Y$ almost surely, hence in distribution. To finish the proof we now show that $\frac Z n +Y$ has a continuous strictly increasing distribution. This is quite easy since this distribution is given by $\int F_n(x-y)dG(y)$ where $F_n$ is $N(0,\frac 1 {n^{2}})$.

Comment: Very clean! But here you very heavily used the fact that this was in one dimension. Any idea for higher dimensional analogues?

Comment: Your question is specifically for real line. If you want to know the multi-dimensional case you should ask a separate question. @Rikimaru